# How to make VIEW returns serialized data?

Tags: django, tastypie

The URL is been overwritten in the following example so that I could pass something like
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/entry/1234/1233/?format=json, doing that will pass parameters to a WRAP VIEW, when I do self.create_response(request, data), the browser only shows something like

> api.Entry object at 0x2e27a50

in the browser, the fields do not get serialized:
Note: I dont need ModelResource at this stage. How can I make the custom view dispatch_data to return data like obj_get and get_object_list? The following is the problematic piece of code:

```
#Object class
Class Entry(object)
    name = ''


#Resource class
class EntryResource(Resource):
    name = fields.CharField(attribute = 'name')

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'entry'
        object_class = Entry
        include_resource_uri = False 
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        serializer = Serializer()

    def override_urls(self):
        return [url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<p1>[\d]{4})/(?P<p2>[\d]{4})%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('dispatch_data'),name='api_dispatch_data'),]

    def dispatch_data(self, request, **kwargs):
         p1 = kwargs['p1'] #params can be retrieved here
         p1 = kwargs['p2']
         info = Entry()
         info.name = p1 #just example
         response = {1:info}
         return info.values() 
         #Above results in ERROR, it will say Entry object has no attribute 'has_header' 
         #changing to self.create_response(request, info) will not serialize the fields



#urls.py
api = Api(api_name='v1')
api.register(EntryResource())

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api/', include(api.urls)),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the Tastypie's [Using Tastypie With Non-ORM Data Sources](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/non_orm_data_sources.html) has all the info you need.

Basically you should implement the methods responsible for returning objects (and/or creating, deleting, etc... if you need them). You don't need to touch "dispatch()" unless you need to customize what it does.

This depends on your needs, but if you want the Resource to act like if it had obj_get and obj_get_list you need to implement the two. The example I mentioned is quite good and should get you going...